# Rest Framework serializer to create parent and one of multiple child types

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a serializer that creates a parent model, then creates a child model depending upon some information provided to the parent:

```
class InitializeFormSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    category = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORY_TYPES)

    def create(self, validated_data, user):
        identifier = validated_data.get('title')

        obj, created = Parent.objects.update_or_create(
            user=user,
        )

        if created:
            item_type = validated_data.get('item_type')
            if item_type == 'FIRST_TYPE':
                Child1.objects.create(identifier=obj)
            elif item_type == 'SECOND_TYPE':
                Child2.objects.create(identifier=obj)

        return obj
```

This works, but the `item_type` check feels clumsy. Is there a paradigm within Django or Rest Framework I'm missing that might make this more elegant?

**EDIT**: By elegant, I mean this is very manual, and does not scale well. I guess my question is, does Django or Rest Framework provide a builtin method for creating a type of child model in the parent serializer.

Comment: `elegant` is a matter of choice ... If so, you can add a dict like this `items = {'FIRST_TYPE': Child1, 'SECOND_TYPE': Child2}` then `if items.get(item_type): items[item_type].objects.create(identifier=obj)`, like this you can reduce your `if clause` to only one.

Comment: That's true - apologies, I've updated the question to clarify what I mean by elegant. I'll most likely take this approach - if you add this as an answer I'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: I see, you can always add a `post_save` signal to your `Parent` model and pass your `item_type` and you can handle the creation of your records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have to implement a method which strategy must vary depending on a parameter, I usually use this pattern. It easies the scalability because you only have to add keys to the strategies dictionaries (in this case, `children_types`). In your case, they are models, but they can be methods, lambdas, or anything else.

```
class InitializeFormSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    category = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORY_TYPES)

    def create(self, validated_data, user):
        children_types = {
            'FIRST_TYPE': Child1,
            'SECOND_TYPE': Child2,
        }

        identifier = validated_data.get('title')

        obj, created = Parent.objects.update_or_create(
            user=user,
        )

        if created:
            item_type = validated_data.get('item_type')
            children_types[item_type].objects.create(identifier=obj)

        return obj
```

Hope it is useful.